# How can I add class to second td in row if last one td (8) has some content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add class to second td in row if last one td (8) has some content?

Html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Jquery

```
$('td:nth-child(8):not(:empty)').closest('tr').addClass('part');
```

CSS

```
table
{border:1px solid #333;}

td
{border:1px solid #333;}

.part
{background-color:red;}
```

FIDDLE

https://jsfiddle.net/jpLq21jv/

Answer (score 1):

Use `.find()` with `:nth-child` selector:

```
$('td:nth-child(8):not(:empty)').closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').addClass('part');
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jg8u12fz/)**

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [`.siblings(selector)`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) at this context,

```
$('td:nth-child(8):not(:empty)').siblings('td:nth-child(2)').addClass('part');
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jpLq21jv/1/)

Answer (score 1):

try this script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr').each(function() {
        if($(this).find('td:nth-child(8)').text().length > 0) {
            $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').addClass("part");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it

```
$('td:nth-child(8):not(:empty)').siblings('td:nth-child(2)').addClass('part');
```

Change in the css also

```
part
```

replace with

```
.part
```